# table rates weight vs destination

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, ce-1.9.0.1, table-rates

I am using table rates weight vs destination for  different shipping rate for different weight. The problem is when the user checks out with e.g. 45 kg item in cart, the shipping rate for 15 kg is applied. so whatever the weight of the item in the cart is, the shipping rate remains the same as that of 0 to 15 kg.

Here's the table:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the contents of `tablerates.csv`?

Comment: yes i am able to add different rates for different weights and upload it as well

Comment: what is the content of the file, can you edit your question and add the content of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i figured what the real problem is. I displayed the total weight that i check out with in the shopping cart and since the minimum weight of the product entered at the time of product entry is 500 gr so when i multiply the quantity with the weight for eg 3 multiplied by 500 gr it displays 1.5 kg in the cart and so the shipping charges remain 95. i have custom optional weights for that product eg 15 kg when selected it doesn't update the total weight with 15 kg and that is why the shipping rate won't change

Answer (score 0):

this is a feature, not a bug.
In your example, the biggest value for 'Weight (and above)' is 13 (before you deleted it from the question).
This means that every weight for 13 or more will use that value (105). 
If you want something different your have to add a new row with the weight value and the price.

Comment: i was not able to paste the entire table and according to the contents it must charge 105 for 15 kg but it keeps the rate 95 I  have attached the table please take a look

Comment: i think i figured what the real problem is. I displayed the total weight that i check out with in the shopping cart and since the minimum weight of the product entered at the time of product entry is 500 gr so when i multiply the quantity with the weight for eg 3 multiplied by 500 gr it displays 1.5 kg in the cart and so the shipping charges remain 95. i have custom optional weights for that product eg 15 kg when selected it doesn't update the total weight with 15 kg and that is why the shipping rate won't change